# Navigate to page created in a CustomControl with a Theme Generic.xaml in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library

I have a solution in which I have a Windows Phone App project and a ClassLibrary that itself has TemplatedControl.cs whose default style is referenced in the **ClassLibrary/Themes/Generic.xaml** Resource Dictionary.

```
- MySolution
    - WPApp_Project
        - MainPage.xaml/MainPage.xaml.cs
        - App.xaml/App.xaml.cs

    - ClassLibrary_Project
        - Themes
            - Generic.xaml
        - View
            - CustomPageControl.cs
        - ViewModel
            - CustomPageViewModel.cs
            - ViewModelLocator.cs
```

Now, in my `Generic.xaml` I have the following style for the `CustomPageControl.cs`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="using:MyClassLibrary.View">

    <!-- Declare the ViewModelLocator as a Resource -->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" xmlns:vm="using:MyClassLibrary.ViewModel" />   

    <Style TargetType="view:CustomPageControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="view:CustomPageControl">
                    <Page DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=CustomControlViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <TextBlock Text="I'm in the Custom Control Page" />
                    </Page>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now in my WPApp I want to navigate from my MainPage to the CustomControlPage that I created in the ClassLibrary, something like:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(CustomPageControl));
```

The problem is that CustomPageControl itself is a Control, not a Page, however, it is connected to a Page style in the `Generic.xaml`, so how can I get that page instance to pass it to my navigation?

**UPDATE**
What I have managed to do is to create a new MainPage2/3/4 in my WPApp and then set it's content as my CustomControlPage. However, this is not my preferable solution, since I want to implement my ClassLibrary in several apps and I don't want to have to add the pages I'll need in every new app.

Comment: Why don't you just make a normal page and put the control in it and then navigate to that page?

Comment: Because the ClassLibrary is supposed to be portable, and with your suggestion I have to implement that page in every new app I put my ClassLibrary in.

Comment: That wasn't really clear from your question, and I don't see the downside of having a page in every app, because every app should be different enough. Shared controls and UI elements - yes, but not complete pages. Anyway, you might be able to get the page by traversing the visual tree (there are many implementations online that you can find) to get the first instance of Page type, which would be your page.

Comment: I'll try to make it more clear, thank you for the suggestion. Can you please point or provide an example of the possible solution you're pointing out?

Comment: @igrali I've tried using a TreeHelper, but I can't find an element of type Page inside my CustomPageControl, I've tried looking for a Parent and for VisualChildren. In fact I've even tried looking for an element of type UIElement and nothing is returned, either looking for a Parent or VisualChildren. Also, looking inside the the property inspector does not lead me anywhere.

Comment: I'm attempting to do something similar, specifically navigate to a page defined in a PCL. did you find a solution or is this something that is not possible?